# How can I make sure that my jmeter script can actually login the testing website?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to do a performance testing on a job application site. Any user can open the web page and apply the jobs listed on the web page. However, when you apply for a job, system generates an OTP. User needs to insert this OTP to complete the log in. The good thing is, for testing purpose, this OTP is sent via the URL so that tester can easily extract it from the URL.
I need to prepare a simple jmeter script for this action.

I Already prepared the script for this. But it doesn't take my extracted OTP. In the submit request it says Invalid OTP.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "doesn't take"? If you perform the login manually using your browser does it "take" the OTP or not? Because if it doesn't - it's not JMeter problem, it's a functional defect of the system you're testing.

If you cannot reproduce it manually and it happens only with JMeter first of all make sure that the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the OTP really has its anticipated value. You can do this using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

The easiest way is most probably recording your login flow using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)  and after [correlating](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the OTP you should be able to login successfully. You might also need to take care of other dynamic parameters, for example add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

The key point is that given you send the same request as the real browser does (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be correlated) the request should be "successful" and the system should "take" the OTP.